# Issue with a left join is null on two large tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join, isnull

I am trying to left join is null two very large tables (3.5 million rows) with about 40 columns to get values that are in one table but not another. There is a column with unique identifiers that are input as strings but then changed to `VARCHAR` in order to index.

When I try to do a left join and then check for null values in the right table 1.9 million rows are returned even though there are much fewer rows that are unique to the table.

I've eliminated all whitespace in all rows in the column.

Here is my query-

```
SELECT * 
FROM NC_Statewide t1
LEFT JOIN NC_Statewide-1 t2 on t1.ncid = t2.ncid
WHERE t2.ncid IS NULL;
```

What is the proper way to do this query on such a large file?

Comment: Maybe some of the values have extra spaces, so they don't actually match what's in the other table. Spaces at the end are ignored, but spaces at the beginning or in the middle are not.

Comment: I'm not quite following what you are trying to do, but what you present will give you all the rows of the left table, `t1`, that have no corresponding row in `t2` (with respect to the specified join condition).  Augmented with all-null columns drawn from `t2`, that is.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think that's what he's trying to do. He's saying that it's returning rows from `t1` that *do* have a corresponding row in `t2`, so it's returning more than it should.

Comment: @Barmar is there a fast way to ignore spaces in both tables?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, that's what I am trying to do, but many rows are returned that exist in both tables.

Comment: @PedroOtalora No way that I know of. You can use `REPLACE(ncid, ' ', '')`, but then it won't be able to use the index, so it will be extremely slow.

Comment: You should fix the data so that the strings are stored in a consistent fashion.

Comment: I wouldn't select * in such a query myself - only look for the data you want - and what indices are you using on thiese tables?

Comment: @MageeWorld default index on NCID. Same problem arises if I only select a few columns.